# How to properly configure my tex environment?

Tags: xetex, texlive, latexmk, texmf, texinputs

I'm new using latex and I'm a bit lost about how to properly configure my environments so my compiler is able to find my files.

From what I read, I'm supposed to have a `TEXINPUTS` and `TEXMFHOME` environment variables, with default values, but I don't have them in my env so far. And putting files in `~/texmf` ends up with a not found error.

From what I understand I am not supposed to set this variables myself unless I want to customize them, so what did I missed ?

If I use the command `kpsewhich` the vars seem ok, but still I don't see them in `env`, and neither my build it seems.

My command is :

`latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="xelatex" -use-make file.tex`

I am on Arch with all the `texlive-*` packages installed out of the box.

EDIT:

To be more specific, I'd like to have my shared .cls, .sty, .fontspec, whatever, which I am supposed to put by default in `$TEXMFHOME`, available when I build my pdf. But it seems out of the box this folder is not read, I get a not found error for my files there.
I can obviously export those vars (and it actually works when I do that), but it seems wrong to have to export default values to make it works as expected.

Comment: If you are a new user, why exactly are you messing with `TEXINPUTS`, `TEXMFHOME` or `~/texmf`? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You wont' see these variables in `env` unless you've modified them: 'out of the box', `kpsewhich` uses defaults so they never need to be set by most users ...

Comment: @daleif as I said, I'd like my compiler to use the files in these locations, but it actually don't. So I'd like to know what did I miss so the files I put in `TEXMFHOME` are actually found as they should be from what I read.

Comment: But what exactly did you put in those locations? What is is a new latex user needs that did not come from the texlive you installed?

Comment: My shared .cls, .sty and fontspec for instance.

Comment: Well... I am not much of a TeXpert per se... But, while I have a Max and only had to install [TeXstudio](https://www.texstudio.org/) and [MacTeX](http://tug.org/mactex/), you can always use a free online service like [Overleaf](http://overleaf.com) or [ShareLaTeX](http://sharelatex.com) (Which recently became the same company--[here](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/518-exciting-news-sharelatex-is-joining-overleaf)) for all your TeX needs.